# How can I create database and web service on azure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, web-services, azure, ionic-framework

I working on my school project.My project purpose is movie rating application with ionic.When I will present my application on the phone.I need to get data on the internet.So I have to use cloud system for keep in web service and sql database.Oh also I will using sql database.I want to build database and web service on the azure.But its my first time for azure.How can I migrate my sql database to azure and how can I create web service in azure.Im rookie these things.I need a starting point.I searched on the web but cant find a good tutorial :(

Comment: Unfortunately, tutorial-recommendation questions are off-topic for StackOverflow. As far as you searching the web for materials, I'm wondering if you've spent much time on the Azure site itself, which has a significant amount of getting-started / tutorial material.

Answer (score -1):

If your SQL Database and WebService structure is not a requirement, you can also explore other options such as Mobile Apps. Mobile apps is a workload on Azure specifically built for such scenarios to connect with mobile devices and two way data communication. It uses what is called "Table storage" on Azure. You can start with that and later on move to a no-sql database such as DocumentDB for persistent storage and querying.

You can find a step by step tutorial below on how to create the Mobile apps and connect it to different platform such as Windows Phone, Android or iPhone. The link here is for Android. If you wish to use other platforms you can use the tab to switch to them. It will even give you a sample project that you can download and run directly which can get you started pretty quickly. I also have a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msgulfcommunity/archive/2014/11/26/kickstarting-your-first-cloud-enabled-app-part-1.aspx) around this if you are interested.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-get-started/

Hope this helps!

Comment: While Azure Mobile Apps are interesting, it's not what the OP asked about. They asked about migrating an existing database. And creating a web service. Instead, you introduced several different alternatives (mobile app, table storage, and even DocumentDB). This is not an answer. In all fairness, the question itself is off-topic (as it's asking for a tutorial), but still... you answered a question that wasn't asked.